# Where to add client certificates for Docker for Mac?

Tags: macos, docker, ssl, tls1.2

I have a docker registry that I'm accessing behind an nginx proxy that does authentication using client-side ssl certificates.

When I attempt to push to this registry, I need the docker daemon to send the client certificate to nginx.

According to:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/

There should be a directory called /etc/docker where these certificates can go. This directory doesn't exist on Docker for Mac.

So I thought I'd try putting the certificates inside the virtual machine itself by doing:

docker-machine ssh default

This resulted in docker complaining:
Error response from daemon: crypto/tls: private key does not match public key

I don't believe there is anything wrong with my key pair, and I've done this same setup on linux (much easier) without problems.

Answer (score 6):

4 yrs later Google still brought me here.

I found the answer in the official docs:
(mac) https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/macfaqs/#add-client-certificates
(windows) https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/windowsfaqs/#how-do-i-add-client-certificates

Citing from source:

> You can put your client certificates in
> `~/.docker/certs.d/<MyRegistry>:<Port>/client.cert` and
> `~/.docker/certs.d/<MyRegistry>:<Port>/client.key`.
>
> When the Docker for Mac application starts up, it copies the
> `~/.docker/certs.d` folder on your Mac to the `/etc/docker/certs.d`
> directory on Moby (the Docker for Mac `xhyve` virtual machine).
>
> - You need to restart Docker for Mac after making any changes to the    keychain or to the `~/.docker/certs.d` directory in order for the
>   changes to take effect.
> - The registry cannot be listed as an insecure registry (see [Docker Engine](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/#docker-engine)). Docker for Mac will ignore certificates listed under
>   insecure registries, and will not send client certificates. Commands
>   like docker run that attempt to pull from the registry will produce
>   error messages on the command line, as well as on the registry.

Comment: add the updated link: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/#add-client-certificates

Comment: I think this is the correct link today https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/macfaqs/#how-do-i-add-tls-certificates

Answer (score 1):

Self-signed TLS CA can be installed like this, your certs might reside in the same directory.

```
sudo mkdir -p /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/etc/ssl/certs
sudo cp my_ca.pem /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/#add-tls-certificates works for me and here is short description of how to for users who use

- Docker Desktop
- Mac os system

1. add cert into mac os chain

```
# Add the cert for all users
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain ca.crt

# Add the cert for yourself
security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain ca.crt
```

2. restart Docker Desktop

Answer (score 0):

This is a current "Oct. 2022" docs in Docker for Mac. (I made it clear to see full url!)

- How do I add TLS certificates?( https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/macfaqs/#how-do-i-add-tls-certificates)

> There should be a directory called /etc/docker where these certificates can go. This directory doesn't exist on Docker for Mac.

In my case, I also don't have `/etc/docker` by default. If you use `~/.docker`, the docker desktop will pass alias into `/etc/docker`.

> I don't believe there is anything wrong with my key pair, and I've done this same setup on linux (much easier) without problems.

You can try put your key pairs under `~/.docker/certs.d/Hostname:port`, and restart your Docker Desktop for Mac. As a result, I guess you can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS here is what I do in order to get my host TLS certificates inside the Docker containers:

1. Export the root TLS certs from the MacOS keychain to a local folder on the host: `security find-certificate -a -p /System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain > ~/.local_certs_for_docker/system_roots_certs.pem`
2. Mount the host certificate in a Docker volume to `/etc/ssl/certs/`. For example with `docker run` you can do this: `-p ~/.local_certs_for_docker/certs.pem:/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`

Hope it helps!